# Avoid memory leak with nested suites in CuTest

Tags: c, unit-testing

I recently used Valgrind to analyze my C project using unit tests written using the [CuTest](http://cutest.sourceforge.net/) library. As it turned out, all my `CuSuite`s and `CuTest`s leaked. I am using a master-suite setup where lots of smaller suites are added together into one big suite which I then run.

First I tried to use `CuSuiteDelete` on the master suite, but all the other suites still leaked. In my next attempt I deleted all the other suites first, before the master one. This caused a segfault, because deleting a suite also frees all tests within it. Since adding a suite to another suite simply copies all the `CuTest` pointers, the second call to `CuSuiteDelete` will try to free already freed `CuTest`s.

Is there another way to do this, avoiding both memory leaks and segfault? If not, this is a bug in CuTest. Although unit tests are usually the only thing being run by a process before exiting, this is still undocumented.

Below are some solutions I came up with:

1. Add refcount to every `CuTest`. `CuSuiteAddSuite` would increment this and `CuTestDelete` would decrement it, removing the test only if refcount reaches 0.
2. Add a `CuSuite` array to every suite where `CuSuiteAddSuite` would put added suites. This would probably require a refcount for suites instead.

Comment: I still do not think there is a way to solve this issue with the official version of CuTest. That is why I have created a fork solving this very issue. [github link](https://github.com/jacwah/cutest/tree/fix-delete)